# How do I change database of an entire diagram on Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

Any way to change database property of all tables from a diagram at once? I have one diagram to a MySQL database, now I need to rewrite diagram to Oracle. Is there any way to do this, without need to change tables properties individually ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DBMS Options are usually updated at a package level. You can select the package that contains all the tables, Right Click -> Code Engineering -> Reset DBMS Options.

Also note, you can define how the column datatypes are converted by defining maps. To do this, Settings -> Database Datatypes -> Datatype map.